# Hibernate Validator 5.1.1 is not working in Web application

Tags: spring, validation, spring-security, hibernate-validator, spring-validator

I am using Spring 4.0 and latest Spring Security in my Web application. I want to use the Hibernate validation 5.1.1 Final. But It's not working. The same code works in my JUNIT but not in the web application.

The code which works:

```
@Test
    public void testUserAuthenticationRequestValidation(){
        try{
        UserAuthenticationRequest req=new UserAuthenticationRequest().addUserName("bla").addPasswd("passw");
        Validator validation=Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
        Set<ConstraintViolation<UserAuthenticationRequest>> constraintViolations= validation.validate(req);
        Assert.assertTrue("There are some errors", constraintViolations.size()>0);
        System.out.println(constraintViolations);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Assert.fail();
        }
```

But if I try to use the same code in my web application, it doesn't work, In the below code, I am expecting contraintViolation set not to be empty because I intentionally left both the username & password empty but I always find it empty.

```
@Override
    public UserDetails retrieveUser(String username,
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        LOGGER.debug("About to check authentication for username: {}", username);
        final UserAuthenticationRequest userData = new UserAuthenticationRequest()
                .addUserName(username).addPasswd(
                        authentication.getCredentials().toString());
        Validator validation = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory()
                .getValidator();
        Set<ConstraintViolation<UserAuthenticationRequest>> constraintViolations = validation
                .validate(userData);
        LOGGER.info("Constraints Violations: {}", constraintViolations);
        LOGGER.info("Obejct: username: {} password: {}",
                userData.getUsername(), userData.getPasswd());
        UserDetailVO userDetailVO = new UserDetailVO(
                userInfoService.authenticate(userData));
        return userDetailVO;
    }
```

So far I have also tried in vain initializing the validation bean as shown below and injecting in my Class as well as shown below:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.sell.mystuff.web.security",
        "com.sell.mystuff.web.service" })
@ImportResource({ "classpath*:spring/common-context.xml" })
public class CommonAppContext {

    @Bean(name = "javaxValidator")
    public Validator getValidator() {
        return Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
    }

}
```

I have even tried to explicitly initialized in the validation bean as shown above but nothing seems to be working. 
Below is my partial POM.xml file related to validation api:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: A couple of things. First, Spring comes with its own Bean Validation integration. I am wondering whether you are running in conflicts here. So, you are saying, that there are just no constraint violations, no exceptions and nothing in the logs? If so, have you tried debugging and see what's happening in the validate call. I also recommend to check the log to see which Validator version (if any) bootstraps. Also, I highly recommend not to create the validator factory on each request. The factory is expensive to built and should be cached. You don't need the annotation-processor jar btw.

Comment: I agree Hardy with what you are saying, but I wanted to see why it's not working. That's why I have to create factory in the code just to be sure that I am using the correct validator.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the validator bean configured?

```
<bean id="validator"
    class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>
```

This will bootstrap Bean Validation 1.0 or 1.1, depending on which version of Hibernate Validator you have on the classpath. See also http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html

Even if you plan to manually call the validation, you should do it by retrieving the configured factory bean, since this will guarantee proper caching of the factory.

Comment: Yes, I have this configured in my beans definition.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by adding a later version of javax.el

e.g.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

BTW I didn't need to define a LocalValidatorFactoryBean in my spring mvc config.